# jQuery/mustache, how to composition a variable for mustache variable?

Tags: jquery, mustache

if the mustache variable has

```
 {{variable_1}}, {{variable_2}}, {{variable_3}}
```

if I went to do this:

```
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
   console.log("{{variable_'+i+'}}");
}
```

In this way not display properly.
how can I do this?

thank.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use handlebars like this, also if it had any hope of working, it would print the string `"variable_" + i`, etc.

```
var variable_1 = "variableOne";
var variable_2 = "variableTwo";
var variable_3 = "variableThree";


  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log(window['variable_' + i]);
  }
```